# RewriteRule htaccess: перенаправление

Tags: .htaccess, php

Я хочу ссылку `site.ru/?mod=section&name=login` поменять на `site.ru/login`, но никак не получается. Только если `site.ru/section/login`, а `section` мне не нужен..

```
RewriteRule ^section/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?mod=section&name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ну так убери `section/`

Comment: Так не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?mod=section&name=login
```

Comment: Оно то конечно хорошо, но вот значение GET параметра name меняется. т.е. в конце, на сколько знаю надо писать name=$1. Но что тогда вначале?

Comment: Тогда внимательно перечитайте свой исходный вопрос и попробуйте более точно сформулировать что нужно. Какой должен быть URL с точки зрения пользователя?

Comment: Ну смотрите. site.ru/?mod=section&name=vasya Меняем на site.ru/vasya

site.ru/?mod=section&name=kolya меняем на site.ru/kolya и т.д.

В вопросе как раз нет конкретики URL и стоит name=$1 в моем примере

Comment: Вы смотрите на это с другой стороны, с серверной. А нужно - со стороны конечного URL, то есть с клиентской. Допустим, все запросы вида "site.ru/что-то" будут перенаправляться на ?mod=section&name=что-то. Вас это устроит? Думаю, нет. Поэтому варианты: 1) в URL должно быть явнаое указание на mod=section (ваш исходный вариант) и 2) запросы должны обрабатываться не mod_rewrire, а внутри движка.

Comment: Так я после этого (или перед, не помню) напишу системные перенаправления, а остальное на section. Нечто подобное, например вконтакте. vk.com/page - страницы, а вот например vk.com/support - поддержка

Comment: Так mod_rewrite не умеет заглядывать внутрь движка :) Тогда проще сделать наоборот: фиксированные URL (/support, /about etc) обрабатывать в mod_rewrite явно, а остальное отдавать в движок. Но тут есть и минусы: 1) при добавлении нового фиксированного URL нужно не забывать про .htaccess и 2) задолбаетесь вносить исключения в имена пользователей, которые использовать нельзя.

Проще уж вообще всю обработку перенести в движок, и там уже анализировать REQUEST_URI.